# Swagger UI is not working on Spring-Boot 3 with Spring security and JWT authorization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger-ui, springdoc

I am trying to attach Swagger-UI to my project and for some reason I am not able to access its interface.

I have followed the [Official guide](https://springdoc.org/#Introduction) + some other guide from the internet.

When I am trying to enter to the paths that's mentioned inside the guide using GET, I am getting error 403.

this is what I've done so far:

1. I have added the following lines into `pom.xml`:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

2. I've added those to my `SecurityConfigurer` class:

   ```
   private static final String[] AUTH_WHITE_LIST = {
           "/v3/api-docs/**",
           "/swagger-ui/**",
           "/v2/api-docs/**",
           "/swagger-resources/**"
   };
   ```

```
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers(AUTH_WHITE_LIST).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/users/createUser").permitAll()//todo fix in the future
                        .requestMatchers("/users/getProfile").permitAll()//todo fix in the future
                        .requestMatchers("/users/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers("/contacts/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
```

Those are my spring dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Start Spring Security in debug mode, change logging levels to info or debug (not quiet sure here) and read what your terminal is saying if you try to load your endpoint in your browser.
What you posted seems valid so far, but there are lot of possibilities what is misconfigured.

Comment: Make a test and see if it works with postman. What kind of authentication do you use? based on credentials or access token?

Comment: Please share: 1. exact url you are using for test 2. full error message you get 3. check if you have any server.servlet.context-path defined in application.properties

Comment: Thank you guys, I needed to add the Authorization JWT token to the browser using an addon. 
But its feeling like bad practice, how can I implement the JWT token automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to upgrade springdoc to version 2.2.0 (`org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.2.0`).

I think you have compatibility problem of spring-boot 3.1 and springdoc 2.1. According to springdoc release notes they upgraded spring boot to 3.1 version in 2.2.0 release (https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/releases/tag/v2.2.0).

You can also exclude `/error` endpoint from security checks (`.requestMatchers("/error").permitAll()`). I think Spring is trying to redirect to this page (due to 404 error) but without authentication it can't show error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!